# rails observe_fields for dynamic menus

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to make a simple nested dynamic menus, where subcategories will be shown based on what I choosed in category. But to make it very simple, I just wanted to render the same thing in the subcategory, whether I choosed "Home" or "Job" (mainly a text of "show the same" will be rendered)

In index.rhtml I have this

```
<html>
<head>
       <%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
</head>
<body>

<select id="categories" name="categories">
    <option value="1">Home</option>
    <option value="2">Job</option>
</select>

<%= observe_field "categories", :update => "subcategories",
 :url => { :controller => "hello", :action => "getsubcategories" } %>

<select id="subcategories" name="subcategories">
    <option>
    </option>
</select>

</bod>
</html>
```

For controller, I have this

```
class HelloController < ApplicationController

def index
end

def getsubcategories
    puts "Got inside the controller"
end  

end
```

and for getsubcategories.rhtml, there is only 1 line

```
   <option value="<%= subcategory.id %>"><%= "show the same" %>
```

It shows an error that points to layout.erb, that can not render correctly on the subcategories menu. I recogn that most likely the mistake is in getsubcategories.rhtml, but I tried several different ways, and still the same error.

How can I fix this? Thank you for any guidance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need desactivate the layout to this action

```
def getsubcategories
  render :getsubcategories, :layout => false
end
```

Comment: ah thank you! I have another question, is it possible to update the second select table by using a certain parameters from the first table. Example, select table 1 (from database) has a key value linked to select table 2 (again from database). I selected 1 option from select table 1, and in select table 2, will just show option from the database that has the same key with select table 1?

Comment: If my answer is good upvote it and accept it. If you have another question. Made a new question.